# retrieve data from a class inside another class

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I have the following html code

```
<span class="tag" style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="/tag/Black+Library" target="_top">Black Library</a><span class="count"> (1)</span> </span>
```

and i want to retrieve number "(1)" from class count inside class tag... how can i do that with jsoup?

code like

```
Elements num = document.select(".tag count");
```

is not working.

In fact i want both the "tag" Black Library and the "count" 1.. Any help to do that?

PS. there is another class count, for which the html code is

```
<li class="gap"><a href="/work/9767358/reviews/78536487">Reviews</a> <span class="count">(0)</span></li>
```

but i dont want that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Elements num = document.select(".tag count");
```

This will select elements with `class="tag"` attribute and then it will in its children look for `<count>` elements. But you actually want to look for elements with `class="count"` attribute. Fix the CSS selector accordingly:

```
Elements num = document.select(".tag .count");
```

#### See also:

- [W3 CSS3 selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
- [Jsoup CSS selector syntax cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)